# В случае (,) если - разделять ли запятой?

Tags: запятые, союзы

Помогите, пожалуйста. Не могу разобраться, нужно ли разделять союз "в случае если" запятой.
Вот примеры:
В случае (,) если все поля заполнены верно, в течение 5 дней Вы получите письмо с одобрением.
В случае (,) если вы указали неполные данные, такой запрос тоже будет обработан оператором.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта. Например:

***В случае если** все поля заполнены верно, в течение 5 дней Вы получите письмо с одобрением.*

***В слУчае, если** вы указали неполные данные, такой запрос тоже будет обработан оператором.*

При расчленении союза падежная форма "в случае" выделена **логическим ударением.**

**В деловом стиле** и в начале предложения союз чаще не расчленяется, но возможно влияние **разных факторов**: распространенность предложения, наличие частиц "а только в случае", "в случае же".

Логическое подчеркивание чаще делается при рассмотрении **альтернативных** вариантов.

**ПРАВИЛО**

**В СЛУЧАЕ(,) ЕСЛИ, союз**  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?lay

Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «в случае(,) если», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но может и расчленяться (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза, перед словом «если»).

***Но в случае, если** заблагорассудите сделать из сего моего письма какое-либо употребление, всепокорнейше прошу никак имени моего не упоминать*... А. Пушкин, Повести покойного Ивана Петровича Белкина. ***В случае если** присяжные закатают меня,* то я обращусь к своему старому другу… А. Чехов, Ночь перед судом.